# CSS list margin between elements in new line

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a simple shop layout. I want to display some 'hot' items.
Each item is a 100x70 box with an 36x32 image and under text. Each element has to have 15px margin between it.

So what I did is margin-left for every element, and disabled margin-left for first child.
But look what happens now, if I have a new line, this will happen:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/eea6b80feb3c36e9d26ab8f1cbf3dd46.png))</sub>

See the extra margin that my margin-left causes on the new line?

How can I prevent this? my css:

```
#hot {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#hot li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

#hot li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

#hot li img {
    display: block;
    width: 36px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#hot ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#hot li span {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```

Example html:

```
        <div id="hot">
            <span id="hotItems">Hot items</span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://www.runelocus.com/img/items/144845.png" />
                    <span>A meme</span>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cgbR9/

Comment: maybe you can just use a margin-right and reset it to last-child if needed ?

Comment: @user3123545 can you create a fiddle please ?

Comment: @SajadLfc http://jsfiddle.net/cgbR9/ - see, extra margin on 2nd row, what i want to do, is clear margin on new row

Comment: @user3123545: now try my answer and if it fixes your problem

Comment: GCyrillus' comment is correct

Comment: Yeah @GCyrillus solution worked, can you answer that so I can accept it

Comment: okay, great for you, i just edited an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay, here it goes :

> maybe you can just use a `margin-right` and reset it to `last-child`
>   if needed ?